# BlazorWebAssembly OpenidConnect in Github does not loaded properly in Visual Studio

Tags: blazor, openid, itfoxtec-identity-blazor

I downloaded your codes in your github (https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWebAssembly.OpenidConnect) and tried to load in visual studio (Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.9.2). I am not able to load the directory under src.  Would you please take a look at it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be caused by to long file names. I have shortened the file names in the solution. Please try again.

Remark: If you download the code as a ZIP file it is probably necessary to move the solution to another place with a shorter file path.

Comment: It works like charm now.  Thanks a lot for your help!